# Continuous merging of multiple Mercurial repositories

Tags: mercurial, multiple-repositories

I'm working on a website that has been in production for some year now. Soon I will start working on a new version, and its initial repository will be a copy of the current site's repository. After the setup of the new repositories, the two repositories of the current site and the new site will diverge. However, if I fix a bug in the current website, I'd like to merge that fix into the new website.

Until recently I used TFS, which made it easy to merge two different versions of a repository (in TFS they're called branches), but how can I achieve this using Mercurial? So far, I've only found instructions on how to merge two different repositories with the intent of discontinuing the oldest repository.

Cheers,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, Djc. It appears that just after asking this question at StackOverflow, I found the answer myself at Mercurial's site:  https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergingUnrelatedRepositories

Comment: They aren't unrelated repositories in your case. The second was a copy of the first so they are related as far as mercurial is concerned. This means that you don't need to specify `-f` on the pull command.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a problem. You can just merge from the old site into the new site, and continue to do so for as long as you want.